# glutSolidSphere and GL_LINE_STRIP drawing in different place but based on the same position

Tags: c, opengl

I am creating a planet simulation which has glutSolidSpheres orbiting a sun and should have trail lines following it, created using GL_LINE_STRIP.

The issue I am having is that the trail does not follow the planet directly behind it, it looks as if it is showing up whatever distance the planet is from the sun, but on the other side. Please see the image below to see what I mean.

[image]

The planets are stored in a Doubly Linked List and each contains a Linked List to store positions for the trail. Each time the planets position is updated, that position is added to the trail.

The code used to draw the trail lines can be seen below:

```
for (struct planet *planet = head; planet != 0; planet = planet->next) {
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(planet->position[0], planet->position[1], planet->position[2]);//X, Y, Z
        glutSolidSphere(planet->mass, 10, 10);//Radius, slices, stacks
        if (!planet->isSun) {
            if (planet->trailStarted) {
                glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
                glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
                glLineWidth(1);
                for (struct trail *trail = planet->trailHead; trail != 0; trail = trail->next)
                {
                    glVertex3f(trail->position[0], trail->position[1], trail->position[2]);
                }
                glEnd();
                glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
            }
        }
        glPopMatrix();
    }
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

The positions do follow each other as they should, printing out the results within the for loop you see above gave the following from this simulation. P is for the planets position, T is for the trails positions:
[image]

If anyone can shed any light as to why it does this, that would be great. If you need any further information please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's already an active translation from line:

```
glTranslatef(planet->position[0], planet->position[1], planet->position[2]);
```

Which means that the origin of the coordinate system is at the planet. So when you draw, you either need to subtract the planet coordinates:

```
for (struct trail *trail = planet->trailHead; trail != 0; trail = trail->next)
{
    glVertex3f(trail->position[0] - planet->position[0], trail->position[1] - planet->position[1], trail->position[2] - planet->position[2]);
}
```

Or you need to do a glPopMatrix() before drawing the trail.
I would prefer the second option:

```
for (struct planet *planet = head; planet != 0; planet = planet->next) {
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(planet->position[0], planet->position[1], planet->position[2]);//X, Y, Z
    glutSolidSphere(planet->mass, 10, 10);//Radius, slices, stacks
    glPopMatrix();
    if (!planet->isSun) {
        if (planet->trailStarted) {
            glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
            glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
            glLineWidth(1);
            for (struct trail *trail = planet->trailHead; trail != 0; trail = trail->next)
            {
                glVertex3f(trail->position[0], trail->position[1], trail->position[2]);
            }
            glEnd();
            glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
        }
    }
}
glFlush();
glutSwapBuffers();
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! I knew it was going to be something stupid I was missing. Thanks!